# how should autograder pass its own text files?

Tags: python

i write my code which i need to pass the autograder which input its ows 10 files 1 by 1 to perform test what should i need to change in my code so that it will automatiaclly input its own file 1 by 1.How should i write the file input code part?

my code

```
filename = input()

L = []
fileToProcess = open(filename, "r")
for line in fileToProcess:
   L.append(line.strip().split(' '))
#print(L)

lst2 = [item[0] for item in L]
# print(lst2)
mylist = list(set(lst2))
#print(mylist[0])

sum_1_M = 0
sum_1_W = 0
list_1 = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for x in L:
        if x[0] == mylist[i] and x[1] == 'M':
            sum_1_M += int(x[2])
            count = count + 1
        elif x[0] == mylist[i] and x[1] == 'W':
            sum_1_W += int(x[2])
            list_1.append(int(x[2]))
            list_1.sort()
    print('{} {} {} {}'.format(mylist[i], list_1[0], list_1[len(list_1) - 1], int(sum_1_M / count)))
    sum_1_M = 0
    sum_1_W = 0
    list_1 = []
    count = 0
```

output

```
507 1000 1000 6
1 1400 1700 7
```

error when i run a code on autograder is this [image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"what should i need to change in my code so that it will automatiaclly input its own file 1 by 1."_? Do you want to A) manually enter all filenames at the same time; B) enter the filenames at the command line when you execute the program; C) read the files in the current directory (or any target directory) with a certain filename mask?

Comment: @aneroid no this is my input file name input.txt and 9 other inputs files The auto-grader pass its own file to process in my code 1st it enter fillename=cows.txt then it pass cowswithzeromilk.txt and so on but when i run my code on auto-grader it wont read the file.

Comment: @aneroid automatically enter filename 1 by 1 not at a same time.

Comment: Explain what you mean by _"but when i run my code on auto-grader **it wont read the file**"_. What is the output of `print(L)` at the top?

Comment: @aneroid check i update my post with a pic a . Internal error for all the test cases.

Comment: Okay, so this is all about the filename input _only_. Do you know _how_ autograder passing in the filename? I suspect it's via parameters/arguments to your program and not via manual input. ie. Print the output of `sys.argv`

Comment: @aneroid i cant understand what you are saying . Can you change my code so autograder pass its file 1 by 1 . Its passing as a argument i think.

Comment: @aneroid can you look this post i describe it in detail what i am trying to do [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463865/calculate-sort-and-report-minimum-most-recent-average-of-a-sequence-of-a-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I suspect that Autograder is passing in the filename as a parameter to your program, and not manual or automated input. Use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to access the parameters passed in to your program.

Most likely, you need to do this:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
```

The rest of your program remains the same.

---

Btw, merely opening a file like `fileToProcess = open(filename, "r")` is not great, since you haven't closed the file later and there's no implicit error handling. The correct way would be:

```
with open(filename, "r") as fileToProcess:
    for line in fileToProcess:
        L.append(line.strip().split(' '))
```

This closes the file after the `with` block, even if errors might occur within the block.